# cant click on <a> tag using ElasticStack

Tags: javascript, touch, swipe

I want to implement ElaticStack in my mobile website (mobile only). But I'm facing a problem: I have added a `<a href="#">TAP ME</a>` in every slide and I want an alert box when user click on `<a>`. The alert is coming in desktop but not in mobile. Please check **fiddle** **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/nzU2H/7/)**

Comment: Instead using alerts in mobile. jQuery Mobile Dialogs would be a choice to do this.

Comment: Thanks for reply @AnthonyLaw.. I agree with I dont want to show alert . Its just for testing purpose.. I just want a click event which is not coming in mobile...

Answer (score 0):

You should add a class to the element you want to attach the event, and then bind the [touchstart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchstart) event.

Something like this:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass");
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element = elements[i];
    element.addEventListener("touchstart", function (event) {
            alert("touch!"); }, false);
}
```